# SWI Prolog description of call/1: "clauses may have variables as subclauses"?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

The description of [call/1](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/1) says:

> `call(:Goal)`
>
> Invoke *Goal* as a goal. Note that clauses may have variables as
>   subclauses, which is identical to `call/1`.

I don't understand "clauses may have variables as subclauses".

Can anyone give an example?

Comment: That's nonsense: Clauses may have variables as goals. And such a variable `X` is identical to `call(X)`. Example: `mycall(G_0) :- G_0.`

Comment: @false Ok, so .. syntactic sugar allowing one to elide the call to `call/1`.

Comment: Sugar? This was a very, very expensive part to resolve, think of `G_0 = !`

Comment: @false What's the semantics of `G_0 = !`?

Comment: The question was: Should it cut or not.

Comment: @false Thanks. Can you think of a paper that describes the design problems for that?

Comment: "**a** paper"? This was a discussion taking place since DEC10 1978 or so and it did not stop in 1995. That is, even after publication of the standard, many believed to have better approaches thereby contributing to even more, er, diversity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Body conversion (*7.6.2 Converting a term to the body of a clause*) à la ISO core standard requires that variables directly inside control constructs inside a body of a clause are wrapped by `call/1`.

Here is an example:

```
?- [user].
and(X,Y) :- X,Y.
^D
?- listing.
and(X,Y) :- call(X), call(Y).
```

The effect is that calling a `!` has no effect, since the cut is confined inside `call/1`.

This is seen here:

```
?- [user].
p(a).
p(b).
?- p(X), !.
X = a
?- and(p(X),!).
X = a ;
X = b
```

**Edit 31.12.2019:**
A Prolog system might want to add (*->)/2 (soft cut) to those control constructs whose arguments are converted thus amending 7.6.2.

---

## From ISO/IEC 13211-1: 1995 Prolog

> **7.6.2 Converting a term to the body of a clause**
>
> A term `T` can be converted to a goal `G` which is the body of a
>   clause:
>
> a)
>
> If `T` is a variable then `G` is the control construct call (7.8.3), whose argument is `T`.
>
> b)
>
> If `T` is a term whose principal functor appears in table 9 then
>   `G` is the corresponding control construct. If the principal functor of `T` is `call/1` or `catch/3` or `throw/1` then the arguments of `T` and `G` are identical, else if the principal functor of `T` is `(',')/2` or `(;)/2` or `(->)/2` then each argument of `T` shall also be converted to a goal.
>
> c)
>
> If `T` is an atom or compound term whose principal functor `FT`
>   does not appear in table 9 then `G` is a predication whose predicate
>   indicator is `PT`, and the arguments, if any, of `T` and `G` are
>   identical.

And

> **7.8.3 call/1**
>
> `call(G)` is true iff `G` represents a goal which is true.
>
> When `G` contains `!` as a subgoal, the effect of `!` shall not extend
>   outside `G`.

And

**Table 9 on page 37: Principal functors and control constructs**

- `(',')/2`          goal arguments converted
- `(;)/2`            goal arguments converted
- `(->)/2`           goal arguments converted
- `!/0`
- `call/1`           goal arguments not converted
- `true/0`
- `fail/0`
- `catch/3`          goal arguments not converted
- `throw/1`

Comment: Accepting as answer! The text at the SWI Prolog website should be changed.

Comment: @David: Key is the precise point in time when this conversion happens. You can observe this moment by adding non-goals like `1`. The error happens precisely at that moment.